# Oracle deduping

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have the following data:

```
ID    ID2      DATE
 A     AA    2017-01-01
 A     BB    2017-01-01
 A     CC    2017-01-01
 B     DD    2018-01-01
 B     DD    2018-01-01
 C     EE    2018-02-01
```

I would like to dedupe by ID keeping only one ID2 and one date per row. I am trying this sql command, but it doesn't dedupe:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.ID2, A.DATE  
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY A.ID;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems that you don't care which `ID2` and `DATUM` (as you can't name a column "`DATE`"; it is reserved for the datatype) you'd want to keep, a simple option is

```
SQL> with test (id, id2, datum) as
  2    (select 'a', 'aa', date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'a', 'bb', date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  4     select 'a', 'cc', date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  5     select 'b', 'dd', date '2018-01-01' from dual union all
  6     select 'b', 'dd', date '2018-01-01' from dual union all
  7     select 'c', 'ee', date '2018-02-01' from dual
  8    )
  9  select id, min(id2) id2, min(datum) datum
 10  from test
 11  group by id;

ID  ID2 DATUM
--- --- ----------
a   aa  2017-01-01
b   dd  2018-01-01
c   ee  2018-02-01

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, id2, date
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can change the `order by` if there is a particular date that you want, such as the minimum or maximum date.